# Why can't you nest a type inside a protocol? Future feature?

Tags: swift, protocols

This isn't a compiler bug, except the last example (Outer3), because the language reference doesn't say you can do it. But why can't you declare a nested type within a protocol? It would be a useful way to group related types. If you try, you get the following errors in beta 4:

```
protocol Outer1 {
    protocol Inner1 {} // Type not allowed here
}

protocol Outer2 {
    struct Inner2 {} // Type not allowed here
}

protocol Outer3 {
    class Inner3 {} // No error, looks promising - BUT!
}

class Test : Outer3 {} // Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'Outer3'
```

The last example, class within protocol, is intriguing because it hints at a partial implementation where the protocol accepts the nested class but then the protocol cannot be implemented. Does this hint that nested types within protocols are on the cards for Swift 2.0?

Comment: Opinion based. Only Apple can answer this now. Please, refer to Apple dev forums.

Comment: Well, what if `Test` declares its own inner class `Inner3`?